# How do I open the layout editor in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I can't find the "layout" folder that I see other people have. I don't know if it is because of something on my end or not.
[Screenshot of someone who has the layout editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtDxD.png)
[Screenshot of my res folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLTOC.png)

Just tried looking around, haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a project with "Empty Activity" then the main activity uses Jetpack Compose and that doesn't need any layout XML file. hence you don't see the layout folder as there are no other layouts.

If you create a `Basic Views Activity` and activity with a layout file will be created. Or you can create a layout file with `File > New > XML > Layout XML file`